# What is a "dead raise"?

Tags: tournament, raise

I've been watching some episodes of Poker After Dark (the tournament episodes) and heard the dealer say that if the players try to straddle, it will be considered a "dead raise". But what exactly is that? I can't seem to find this term defined anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you straddle in the traditional sense in a poker room that allows them, it's considered a "live" straddle. Several popular variations of straddling exist, but one common element is that they're "live."  This means that the straddler is paying for the privilege of acting last in the pre-flop round of betting. If the dealer in your example is saying that it's a "dead" raise, that simply means that the bet is not a live straddle but rather just a bet placed blindly that doesn't confer any additional benefits.

Comment: Even though it is not a live straddle, as you said, it would still be binding and would allow the player to, effectively, act last, correct?

Comment: If the dead raiser is UTG and puts in 2 BB before the hand and it's called around back to him, he doesn't get to re-raise himself. If this were instead a live straddle, he would have the option to effectively raise himself.

Comment: If the dealer declares the straddle to be a dead raise (usually because he did not put the straddle out before the dealer started to deal the cards), often he will allow the player to take the raise back if no player has yet acted on his hand.  The reason for this is to avoid confusion.  Once a player acts on his hand, the money stays in.  Also, a dead raise means that he no longer acts last.  His action is first - and that action is a min raise.  He does not get another chance to act on his hand again if no one raises like a true straddler would.

Answer (score 1):

It's when the UTG player posts an additional blind and thus is given the chance to act last. This action is not considered a raise to the rest of the table.

Answer (score -3):

From what I have heard , a "Dead Raise" its when you raise without any change to get the pot. You trying to bluff your hand its sure they will pay.

Comment: I think you might be confusing this with something like "drawing dead."